# How to Override this run method calling another method

Tags: java, multithreading, object, methods, queue

I am having a run method which tries to override another run method. But its not happening because I am getting a "Class not found Exception" before it passed on to run method.

Here´s my class with run method

```
  public class PollingSynchronizer implements Runnable{
   public Collection<KamMessage> incomingQueue,outgoingQueue,fetchedMessages;
   private Connection dbConnection;


/**
 * Constructor. Requires to provide a reference to the Kam message queue
 * 
 * @param incomingMessages reference to message queue
 * @param dbConnection 
 * 
 */
public PollingSynchronizer(Collection<KpiMessage> incomingQueue, Connection dbConnection) {
    super();
    this.incomingQueue = incomingQueue;
    this.dbConnection = dbConnection;
}
private int seqId;
public int getSeqId() {
    return seqId;
}
public void setSeqId(int seqId) {
    this.seqId = seqId;
}



@Override
/**
 * The method which runs Polling action and record the time at which it is done
 * 
 */

      public void run() {
    int seqId = 0;
    while(true) {
        List<KamMessage> list = null;
        try {
            list = fullPoll(seqId);
            if (!list.isEmpty()) {
                seqId = list.get(0).getSequence();
                incomingQueue.addAll(list);
                this.outgoingQueue = incomingQueue;
                System.out.println("waiting 3 seconds");
                System.out.println("new incoming message");
                Thread.sleep(3000);
               //when I debug my execution stops here and throws exception
                MessageProcessor processor = new MessageProcessor() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
            new MessageProcessor().generate(outgoingQueue);             
                    }
                };


            }
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

This is the method which I have to call in order to execute.

```
    public abstract class MessageProcessor implements Runnable {
private Collection<KpiMessage> fetchedMessages;
private Connection dbConnection;
Statement st = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
private Collection<KpiMessage> outgoingQueue;


public KpiMsg804 MessageProcessor(Collection<KpiMessage> outgoingQueue, Connection
 dbConnection){
    this.outgoingQueue = outgoingQueue;
    this.dbConnection = dbConnection;
    return (KpiMsg804) fetchedMessages;
}

    public Collection<KamMessage> generate(Collection<KamMessage> outgoingQueue)
   {
    while(true){
        try {

            while (rs.next()) {
                KamMessage filedClass = convertRecordsetToPojo(rs);
                outgoingQueue.add(filedClass);

            }

            for (KamMessage pojoClass : outgoingQueue) {
                KamMsg804 updatedValue = createKamMsg804(pojoClass);
                System.out.print(" " + pojoClass.getSequence());
                System.out.print(" " + pojoClass.getTableName());
                System.out.print(" " + pojoClass.getAction());
                System.out.print(" " + updatedValue.getKeyInfo1());
                System.out.print(" " + updatedValue.getKeyInfo2());
                System.out.println(" " + pojoClass.getEntryTime());
            }
            return outgoingQueue;

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

}
How can I implement this?

Since I am new here, please give a reason for thumbs down. So that I can explain my question.

Comment: _What does the exception say?_

Comment: @SLaks it doesnot return error, but its just looping not moving forward, as I have mentioned in the comments it stops in the first run() method..

Comment: I could find this when I only debug....

Comment: Your comment says that there is an exception. What does "stops" mean?

Comment: What is `MessageProcessor` class? Can you show it's code?

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov, thats the second piece of code I have added with its method, check my update

Comment: I don't see anyway to exit this while(true) loop, and I'm not sure what MessageProcessor is for since you don't do anything with it.

Comment: @SLaks sorry mate ,I meant it keeps on looping instead of executing the seond run method...

Comment: @maddy what do you want to get? Now you are not calling `run` or `start` method anywhere in `MessageProcessor`.

Comment: @JustinJasmann actually this message processor class has a method which gets the values of incoming queue in outgoing queue,updates it and print it back. But since it only looping after the main run() method, My second method is not over riding...

Comment: Your second run() method is never going to run since you only define the MessageProcessor class, and you can't instantiate an abstract class..

Comment: @Justin Jasmann, thanks I will try modifying...

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov all i want to get is the outgoingqueue from the generate method. This method is running in the message processor class, updates the outgoing queue and passes to the run method. how to implement this. right now this is just stopping in the first run method.

Comment: @maddy I still don't understand why don't you just call `new MessageProcessor().generate(outgoingQueue)`.

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov am not so good at programming, my cause to call it was because I want to run this method when the thread sleeps for 3 seconds like parallel processing. But as I execute it stops at thread.sleep(3000) and loops back to main run ().

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov i will try out as you said...

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov I changed the way you said...is this the way... check my update...

Comment: @maddy sorry but if you're not very good at programming you shouldn't try to make at once such complicated programs. It seems you don't fully understand how threads work. Read some tutorials on multithreading in java.

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov, Thank you so much ,I will try to sort out... :)

Comment: @SLaks its Class not found Exception....

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov I found de exception

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
MessageProcessor processor = new MessageProcessor() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
**new MessageProcessor()**.generate(outgoingQueue);             
    }
};
```

1. MessageProcessor is an abstract class. object creation inside the run method should have failed at compile time.
2. processor object is created but unused.. you need to create a thread with the processor instace and start the thread.